# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Compilation error with ATTWLApplicationProject

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, att

Some of the classes like `com.att.PaymentHelper` use the `com.worklight.server.integration.api.JSObjectConverter` class. This class was bundled in the worklight-jee-library.jar in Worklight 5.0.6, but it is not found in Worklight 6.0.0.1.

I also noted from the readme.txt of the [ATT package](http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=13400560) that it is tested only on Worklight 5.0.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in Worklight 6.0.0.x, the `JSObjectConverter` class changed location. 
It is now located at: `com.worklight.common.js.util.JSObjectConverter`.

I have contacted the people in charge of this package with the information mentioned above.

Comment: I downloaded the AT&T package and found that it does not compile in Worklight 6.0.0.1. Thanks, let me change the AT&T code and see if it works.